# C3 chart points are empty circles

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm generating line charts with C3. I see at http://c3js.org/samples/simple_multiple.html that the various points are filled with the same color as the associated line. When I create my line chart, my points are just empty circles. How do I get the points to fill with the line color?

**Empty circles as points:**

[image: C3 graph with non-filled points]

**C3 generation:**

```
                c3.generate({
                    bindto: divReference,
                    data: {
                        x: 'x',
                        columns: columnData,
                        colors: colorData,
                        axes: { data: 'y' },
                    },
                    grid: {
                        x: { show: true },
                        y: { show: true }
                    },
                    axis: {
                        x: {
                            type: 'timeseries',
                            tick: { format: '%m/%d' }
                        }
                    },
                    point: {
                        //stroke: '#ff0000'
                        fill: '#ff0000'
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 2):

Set event "onrendered" like this, for example:

```
onrendered: function () {
            var $$ = this;
            var circles = $$.getCircles();
            for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){
                for(var j = 0; j < circles[i].length; j++){
                $$.getCircles(j).style("fill", '#FFF')
                    .style("stroke", $$.color)
                    .style("stroke-width", 3);
                }
            }
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wfn1s41t/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the color.pattern property at the top level (remove all the other fill colorsData that you set)?

```
c3.generate({
...
  color: {
    pattern: '#ff0000'
  }
})
```

I believe this works for multiple lines as well

http://c3js.org/reference.html

color.pattern
Set custom color pattern.

```
color: { pattern: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a' ] }
```

BTW, if this doesn't work please post a jsfiddle. We should be able to figure it out pretty fast!

Comment: A coworker eventually tracked down the issue. The design company that we are working with had written CSS that was somehow overriding the coloring of the dots. Thanks for taking time to look at the issue, though!